# REST API - request to another account's record returns empty string or HTTP 404?

Tags: api, rest

Should be to the request to resource in REST API that belongs to another account returned `HTTP 404` status code or `HTTP 200` with an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `403 Forbidden`. This is for a case when the resource is present, but the (possibly) logged in user does not have permission to get.

The `404 Not Found` should only be used if the resource is not present, meaning other permissions would not help.

`200 OK` should only be given if the request completed successfully, the client got a valid representation of the resource.

Comment: To inform another user that particular record exists and belongs to another account seems for me like a security issue, isn't it?

Comment: It is a security issue only if the URI leaks some kind of information. Otherwise it helps the client to know what is going on, whether the link is wrong (`404`) or the link was ok, only I'm not logged in (`401`), or link it ok, but I don't have permission to look (`403`).

Comment: For example I can see that if the username is part of the URI, that is a problem. Because the username is normally a part of the login credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Robert Bräutigam that **HTTP 403** seems most appropriate.

However, consider a URL like:

```
/api/some-user-user-id/profile
```

If you return 403 for existing users and 404 for non-existent users - you could be enabling outsiders to discover user ids.

This may or may not be a problem.